# Auto Re-Sizing Tableview cell to the cells content (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to get my tableview to work so when a cell is clicked it resizes to fit the content inside the cell automatically. (Different amounts of text will automatically re-size different.

[Cell when not clicked (first state and size it should go back to when clicked = 44.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/855nY.png)

So with this image, this is the stage each cell will be in only as default and deselected. The white text will be the only thing visible.

[Cell clicked state. resizes to my "let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 88.0
" constant. Which needs to automatically size to fit the green text no matter how much is in there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gv3T.png)

This is my full code for the tableview and viewcontroller.

```
import UIKit

class TasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tblTasks: UITableView!

//For persisting data
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.tblTasks.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 64/255.0, green: 67/255.0, blue: 68/255.0, alpha: 0)


    self.tblTasks.reloadData()
    self.tblTasks.register(UINib(nibName: "WhiteTaskTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "nameCell")
    tblTasks.tableFooterView = UIView()

    let darkModeColor = UIColor(red: 52/255.0, green: 55/255.0, blue: 55/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    view.backgroundColor = darkModeColor


    tblTasks.dataSource = self;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tblTasks.reloadData()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return taskMgr.tasks.count

}



//Define how our cells look - 2 lines a heading and a subtitle
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


    let identifier = "nameCell"
    var cell: WhiteTaskTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? WhiteTaskTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "WhiteTaskTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? WhiteTaskTableViewCell
    }


    //        Assign the contents of our var "items" to the textLabel of each cell
    //        cell.textLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    //        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

    cell.TaskNameLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.NotesLabel.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].note

    cell.selectionStyle = .none



    return cell

}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
}



   func tableView(_ willDisplayforRowAttableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 64/255.0, green: 67/255.0, blue: 68/255.0, alpha: 0)
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

        taskMgr.removeTask(indexPath.row)
        tblTasks.reloadData()
    }
}



   // EXPAND CELL ON CLICK


// Global Variables/Constants

var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 88.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    self.tblTasks.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath as NSIndexPath?  {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath as NSIndexPath? {
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath?
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/


}
```

**I'm open to any help and insight. Thank you very much.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an Outlet to your `UITableView` and set the `rowHeight` parameter to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Also you need set the `estimatedRowHeight` to a value fitting your needs. This way the size of the Cell will fit the size of its content.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()        
      tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 55
      tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For this to work, you need to set the Autolayout Constraints for every element of your Cell.

[Source Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html):

[image]

> **Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells**
>
> In iOS, you can use Auto Layout to define the height of a table view
>   cell; however, the feature is not enabled by default.
>
> Normally, a cell’s height is determined by the table view delegate’s
>   `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. To enable self-sizing table
>   view cells, you must set the table view’s `rowHeight` property to
>   `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. You must also assign a value to the
>   `estimatedRowHeight` property. As soon as both of these properties are
>   set, the system uses Auto Layout to calculate the row’s actual height.
>
> Additionally, try to make the estimated row height as accurate as
>   possible. The system calculates items such as the scroll bar heights
>   based on these estimates. The more accurate the estimates, the more
>   seamless the user experience becomes.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks a bunch! I now understand the concept!